# How to define a uniform probability distribution over a convex polytope / polyhedra and add them?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

Let $P$ be a convex 3d polyhedra / 2d polytope constrained by a set of linear inequalities $Ax<=  b$.

**1.How to define a uniform probability distribution over a polytope/polyhedra?**

Let us say we have multiple polytopes/polyhedra with uniform probability distribution but non-identical due to fact the geometry is not constrained by the same set of inequalities. I

**2. How to add two non-identical yet independent and uniform distributions defined over a polytope/polyhedra?**

***Relavance to the application***: I would like to sample large set of points sampled from each of the convex polytopes and add points from each set among themselves to arrive at a sum distribution of higher probability. I need a theoretical tool to justify that my sampling is good enough to approximate the minkowski sum of polyhedra with an area/volume of higher probability.

Comment: Do you really mean how to *define* this distribution? It seems clear enough how it's defined. I suspect you want to know how to sample from it efficiently? If so, you might want to say more about the specific setting (e.g. the number of faces). One simple approach would be to sample from a bounding box and reject samples outside the polytope, but that might not be efficient enough for large numbers of faces.

Comment: I sample exactly the same way you suggest. I want to approximate the minkowski sum of polytopes by sampling and justify the resulting sum distribution has a good guarantee. I was wondering if I could add these probability distributions by convolution but I'm not sure how to do it for a polytope.

Comment: Here's [another idea](https://beta.observablehq.com/@scarysize/finding-random-points-in-a-polygon) based on triangulation and barycentric coordinates.